# Which person wins the game? Find the person who removes the last balls from the bag.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

I have a game.
Suppose the ball is in the bag and each person can take 1, 2, 3, or 4 balls out of the bag at each stage.
Assuming that each participant (participants A and B) knows how many balls are in the bag and that each person makes the best move in turn, how do we know which one wins?

We only know the number of balls in the bag (also those two people move accordingly)

For example, imagine we have 6 balls in the bag.
`A` is the winner (the best moves of the players)

Comment: I think this is likely a duplicate. Let me see if I can find it...

Comment: Ok, it's not a duplicate, but it's very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3212957/26369 , which may help Ali answer their own question.

Comment: True, but this is a little different. Can you offer a solution to this?

Comment: B wins if the initial number is a multiple of 5, A wins otherwise

Comment: Thanks. This is work :)